# How do I add a class to the current image in a slideshow?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a slideshow that is custom made with JQuery;

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $animating_slideshow = false;
    $animation_speed = 1000;
    $amount_of_slides = $("#slider").find(".img-games").find(".img-game").length;

    $("#slider-left").on("click", function() {
        if (!$animating_slideshow) {
            $slidden = parseInt($(this).parent().find(".img-games").css("margin-left"));
            if ($slidden > 0 || $slidden < 0) {
                $(this).parent().find(".img-games").animate({"margin-left":"+=170"}, $animation_speed, function() {
                    $animating_slideshow = false;
                });
                $animating_slideshow = true;
            } else {
                $(this).parent().find(".img-games").animate({"margin-left":-($amount_of_slides-1) * 170}, $animation_speed, function() {
                    $animating_slideshow = false;
                });
                $animating_slideshow = true;
            }
        }
    });

    $("#slider-right").on("click", function() {
        if (!$animating_slideshow) {
            $slidden = parseInt($(this).parent().find(".img-games").css("margin-left"));
                if ($slidden > -($amount_of_slides-1) * 170) {
                    $(this).parent().find(".img-games").animate({"margin-left":"-=170"}, $animation_speed, function() {
                    $animating_slideshow = false;
                });
                    $animating_slideshow = true;
                } else {
                    $(this).parent().find(".img-games").animate({"margin-left":"0"}, $animation_speed, function() {
                    $animating_slideshow = false;
                });
                $animating_slideshow = true;
                }
        }
    });
});
```

And this is my html...

```
<div id="slider">
        <div class="img-games">
            <div id="this_slide" class="img-game">
                <img src="http://www.maxdamage.org/wp-content/uploads/2012/05/pokemon-gameboy.jpg" width='170px' height='115px' class='degrades' alt='pokemon' title='Pokemon'>
            </div>
            <div class="img-game">
                <img src="http://1.bp.blogspot.com/-U62BIDPN79U/UV1hPr9xtAI/AAAAAAAAENs/mKIrEDb4RAw/s320/Super_mario_land.png" width='170px' height='115px' class='degrades' alt='Mario' title='Mario'>
            </div>
            <div class="img-game">
                <img src="http://1.bp.blogspot.com/-J7x8JfY21Yk/UUea7UsjUZI/AAAAAAAAA0M/E2qpkAZFsnM/s1600/links_awakening2.png" width="170px" height="115px" class="degrades" alt='Zelda' title='Zelda'>
            </div>
            <div class="img-game">
                <img src="http://www.consoleclassix.com/info_img/Rayman_GBC_ScreenShot2.gif" width="170px" height="115px" class="degrades" alt='Rayman' title='Rayman'>
            </div>
        </div>
</div>
```

How would I go about adding a new class called 'current' to the image that can currently be viewed on the screen, any help would be appreciated, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two possible solutions:

1) If you keep track of the current index of the slide show, you can use it to set the class, as follows:

```
$('.current').removeClass('current');
$('.img-game:eq(' + currentIndex + ')').addClass('current');
```

2) When clicking left or right, use the location of the `current` class to reassign the class to somewhere else. The following is a left click example:

```
$('.current').removeClass('current').parent().next().child('.img-game')
    .addClass('current')
```

For a right click, you would use `.prev()` instead of `.next()`. You should also include a check to make sure that the next element exists before changing the selection.

Comment: You, my good sir have just earned yourself one accepted answer! and an up vote